# AlarmManager in Android works only in an emulator and does not on a physical device

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

I created an application with *AlarmManager* and *Notification* but it works only on an emulator. When I run the app on my physical device the notifications are not shown despite the fact that in *app info* there is information about the notifications.

EDIT: I've found the solution in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729966/alarmmanager-not-working-in-several-devices/42468905)

Comment: Please include a snippet of your notification code.

Comment: Have you inserted proper logs to get notified about how the code is behaving?

Comment: @dazza5000 The code is almost the same as it is here: [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64805288/alarmmanager-with-notification-in-android-does-not-show-any-notifications/)

Comment: @NadeemShaikh I inserted logs into the class which extends BroadcastReceiver and it looks like the application does not execute the overriden onReceive method which it should execute in order to show notifications to the user

Comment: @Remi any specific event responsible to trigger the `onReceive` command?

Comment: @Remi In order to reach `onReceive` method you must have to invoke `sendBroadcast(Intent intent)`. Make sure where you have this function written gets invoked.

Comment: @NadeemShaikh `AlarmManager` should trigger the `onReceive` method every minute since `AlarmManager`'s delay is set to 1 minute (1000L * 60L).
User clicks a button and the `alarmManager.setRepeating(...)` is executed

Comment: @NadeemShaikh I will try to implement it

Comment: @Remi check out the answer that I have posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your Alarm completes 60 secs or whenever you need to trigger the notification, invoke the following function:-

```
triggerNotification(){
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),DailyNotificationReceiver.class);
sendBroadcast(intent);
}
//after every min lapsed invoke this function
```

This is in java, convert it into kotlin.
This `sendBroadcast` function will internally call your `onReceive` method

Comment: It worked! It showed a notification only once. It seems like this code does not work: 
`alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, repeatInterval, notifyPendingIntent) `

Comment: done, thank you! 
I'll investigate further the problem

Comment: I've found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34729966/alarmmanager-not-working-in-several-devices/42468905

Comment: @Remi I personally also have experienced such problems in OnePLus devices as well. Some app dont show notifications until opened once. To prevent such problem you need to exempsuch apps in battery optimization. In Oneplus phones there is a setting called "Dont optimize" in Battery settings.

Comment: I've found the guide for my phone here: https://dontkillmyapp.com/xiaomi